# Blacklist a subfolder in rails eager load path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

I need to blacklist routes in an api namespace from every environment except test. Reason being, our integration suite with some microservices using the API needs to wipe the API database in between test runs.

assuming I have the following app directory structure.

```
app
 \_controllers
    \_api
       \_v1
         \_test
            \_test_controller.rb
          base_controller.rb
          some_controller.rb
```

How would I go about blacklisting `controllers/api/v1/test/` but still retaining `app/controllers` in the eager load path?

#### EDIT:

```
  # routes.rb
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :instruments, only: [:index, :show]
      resources :instrument_roots, only: [:index, :show]
      if Rails.env.test? # integration suite handlers
        namespace :test do
          resources :instruments, only: [:destroy]
          post '/reset' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

I'm removing the routes with an environment check, but ideally I wouldn't load the controllers *at all*.

Comment: Can we see your routes.rb?

Comment: @JimVanFleet - updated. This works for not allowing the routes to be hit, but rails still loads the controller objects. Ideally, I'd want it removed entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the subdirectories of `app/controllers` is unlikely to be possible, as the individual directory entries are not present on the load path in the first place.

You may get results from creating a `RAILS_ROOT/test_api_support` (which in turn would have an `app/controllers` directory), and moving these files there.  You could then add that directory to your load path in only your `spec_helper.rb`, `test_helper.rb`, or `config/environments/test.rb`.

This approach should have the effect of removing them from your VM's memory in other environments.

Comment: Yes, I went a similar route where I put the controllers in `/lib` and added that to the eager load path conditionally. Thanks for the help!